# Css para tablet no ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic, scss

Boa tarde,
Como posso fazer um css para celular e tablet? preciso separar, prq em determinada tela o menu deve ser apresentado e em outra não.

Comment: Cara sua pergunta não ficou muito clara. Vc precisa que seja exclusivamente com o métodos do Ionic, explique melhor a realidade da situação que vc precisa controlar o elemento

Comment: Bom dia, preciso de um jeito para q o menu criado pelo modelo do ionic, não apareça na tela de login, e se possível, gostaria que ele funcionasse sempre da mesma forma, fechado e sendo acessado pelo hamburguer.

Comment: Na documentação vc encontra o método que desativa ou ativa o menu: this.menu.enable(false/true); https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu - Não precisa ser em CSS. Quando entrar na página, vc desativa ou ativa o mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo.

Comment: So mais uma duvida, no ion-splt-pane tem um parâmetro when="xl" por exemplo. Existe a possibilidade de criar por exemplo xxl com um valor diferente?

Comment: Não sei se é possivel criar um novo valor, porem, você pode alterar o já existente valor xl, leia mais [sobre](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid#grid-width)